# Scala Collections - type casting Any to Seq[T] using Converters

Tags: java, scala, sbt, scala-collections

I am new to Scala and I am trying to replace the deprecated JavaConversions library with JavaConverters. The original Code looks like this:

```
addresses = {
      import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
      config.getConfigList("amqp.addresses").map(address ⇒
        Address(
          host = address.foo()
        ))(collection.breakOut)
}
```

When I replace the `JavaConversions` with `JavaConvertors` in the code above, I get a compilation error:

```
Type mismatch: expected Seq[Address], actual: Any
```

I understand what the exception means, but I am not sure how I can convert the code above to make is return a `Seq[Address]` and not an `Any`. Also, there is a `asJava` method in Converters to convert the scala list to java list, but not sure how I can use it here. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to state the final type and explicitly convert the Java collection into a Scala one (`asScala`):

```
addresses: Seq[Address] = {
      import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
      config.getConfigList("amqp.addresses").asScala.map(address ⇒
        Address(
          host = address.foo()
        ))(collection.breakOut)
}
```

Comment: thanks! that works. I have a related questions about Converters library, but I opened a new thread for it to keep it clean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673632/scala-collections-util-mapstring-anyref-mapstring-string