# Scala collections: util.Map[String, AnyRef] - Map[String, String]

Tags: java, scala, sbt, scala-collections

I am getting started with Scala and I am replacing the deprecated `JavaConversions` library with `JavaConverters`. I have the following code:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder()
  .contentType(message.contentType.map(_.toString).orNull)
  .contentEncoding(message.contentEncoding.orNull)
  .headers(message.headers) //<<<<--------------- I SEE THE ERROR ON THIS LINE (datatype of message.heads is Map[String, String]
  .deliveryMode(toDeliveryMode(message.mode))
  .priority(..)
  .correlationId(..)
  .replyTo(..)
  .expiration(..)
  .messageId(..)
  .timestamp(..)
  .`type`(..)
  .userId(..)
  .appId(..)
  .build()
```

}

When I replace the import for `JavaConversions` to `JavaConverters` (or, just comment out the import altogether), I get the compilation exception:

```
Type mismatch expected: util.Map[String, AnyRef], actual Map[String, String]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you're missing `.asJava` obviously `util.Map[String, AnyRef]` is a Java collection `Map[String, String]` is a Scala collection

Comment: @dk14 can you please elaborate? Where do I need to add the `.asJava`?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `.asJava` obviously - explicit conversion is the whole point of using JavaConverters. `util.Map[String, AnyRef]` is a Java collection, `Map[String, String]` is a Scala collection. You need at least

```
.headers(message.headers.asJava.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, AnyRef]])
```

or better to do type-cast safely before calling `asJava`:

```
val params: Map[String, AnyRef] = message.headers
...
.headers(params.asJava)
```

P.S. The reason you've got a second error after just doing `asJava` isn't Scala or JavaConvertors related, it's just that `V` in `java.util.Map[K,V]` isn't covariant (it's invariant, unlike in Scala's `Map[K, +V]`). Actually compiler messages explains it:

> Note: String <: AnyRef, but Java-defined trait Map is invariant in type V.

Comment: now I see: Type mismatch expected: util.Map[String, AnyRef], actual util.Map[String, String]

Comment: @Darth.Vader this isn't related to Scala or converters - java's map isn't contra-variant on second argument, so you have to do it java style (typecast). Basically compiler message suggests it: "Note: String <: AnyRef, but Java-defined trait Map is invariant in type V."